# How utorrent implements the "vote" system over the DHT?

Tags: dht

Does anyone know how utorrent implements the "vote" system over the DHT?

I looked online but there is next to nothing about it.

Some information:
http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/bittorrent/2011-January/002413.html

http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1305/1305.0711.pdf

You get a message something like this:

`{ a:
   { id: '907050177fb05376db71ce066663819503eb0a9a',
     target: '546d6d0e5aacfae66299f26a300a428c497b23b5',
     token: '5b3f3de3d4f5ba42721dac14b2076dc64bc829da',
     vote: 0 },
  q: 'vote',
  t: '+=\u0000\u0000',
  v: 'UT??',
  y: 'q' }`

The only thing I dont get it the `target` They say its `sha1(info-hash + "rating")` but i dont know. So the rating 1-5 and 0 been the query for votes. So if a infohash has 5 votes ranging from 1 to 5 would you receive 5 responses?

Has anyone played around with this?